# Obtaining string (json) representation a PostData created out of a multiJson object

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch.net

The following works right:

```
var postDataJson = new
{
    query = new
    {
        match_all = new { }
    },
    sort = new
    {
        _score = "desc"
    }
};

var postData = PostData.MultiJson(new object[] { postDataJson });
```

Is there a way to obtain a json representation out of postData, out of the box ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the serializer on the client to get the JSON string representation. Note, you likely want to serialize just the anonymous type, and not `PostData`, which is used by the client to understand how to serialize the contained type.

```
var client = new ElasticLowLevelClient();

var postDataJson = new
{
    query = new
    {
        match_all = new { }
    },
    sort = new
    {
        _score = "desc"
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(client.Serializer.SerializeToString(postDataJson));
```

Which writes the following to the console

```
{"query":{"match_all":{}},"sort":{"_score":"desc"}}
```

Comment: Hey Russ, thanks. I meant however to get the JSON from a PostData object, not from an anonymous object (for which I have been using PostData.MultiJson). Good to know the api exposes a json serializer, though.